# passing settings to amp-jwplayer plugin

Tags: jwplayer, amp-html

I am tring to use amp-jwplayer as described here: [here](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-jwplayer/)
but  I didn't figure how to customize my player settings, ex: file: image: ... 
any suggestions?

thnaks

Comment: You can refer to the [documentation of amp-jwplayer](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-jwplayer).

Comment: jwplayer is an commercial product, the feautres supported currently by amp does not enable such settings as to streaming content directly from other cdn than jwplayer itself. I have also hard time to find an adequate player for my content. As it seems the only solution which remains is to embed your player into an amp-iframe or if your requirements are not too high use the amp-video element.